# node help: how to make a curve with linear and module

Tags: node-editor

How do I do it node in curve?
image 2: curve but i used modifier
[image: in line]

[image: In curve - but i used modifier]

Comment: You mean warp a texture in shader nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a Vector Math node.

Start with the horizontal band texture that you want to warp (I used a wave texture cut with a ColorRamp as an example).

[image: Warp1]

Pick another texture to use as a "warp factor". I used a wave texture set on the Y axis. I didn't use a ColorRamp, because the natural gradient of the texture will help make the wave "curve" smoothly.

[image: Warp2]

Then, use a Vector Math node to add the Color output of the "warp factor" texture to the original input vector. Use the result as a vector for your initial horizontal band texture. I added a MixRGB Node between the warp factor texture and the Vector Math node, because it lets you control the strength (and therefore the warp factor) of the texture output by changing the mix factor.

[image: Warp3]

Comment: thanks helped much